# Add New Data Source and code in connection with mismatch

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm doing the project with c # sqlite
I'm starting to connect with the code.
updating, deleting, listing procedures
I'm with the code

```
  string connect = @"Data source=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\yedek\\DUKKAN.db3; Journal Mode=Off"
```

this connection good work.

but  Add New Data Source  connection this map wrong
image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XN3f.png

If I choose to browse on different computers, this error "unable to open database"
I use the other connection for reporting (for dataset)

consequently
the database is running
reporting does not work

this project screen (work) database insert, select  and update work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ0MD.png

this project report(use microsoft report viewer) not work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrrFK.png

Comment: @"Data source="\\yedek\\DUKKAN.db3 seems wrong to me this is not a string. maybe something like "Data source=" + "@\\yedek\\DUKKAN.db3"

Comment: but this work connectitonstring                  

connect= @"Data source="\\yedek\\DUKKAN.db3; Journal Mode=Off";

Comment: How this is not a in the "" \\yedek\\DUKKAN.db3 this is the error

Comment: this work ... please picture
http://i.imgur.com/kZO2XT8.png

dont work other visual data winzard connection

Comment: step through your code in debug it can not work.

Comment: I saw right now
sorry im change code  string cumle = @"Data source=" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\yedek\\DUKKAN.db3; Journal Mode=Off";  
How should the visual connection  this photo http://i.imgur.com/DSEsGxS.png

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the full path and file name in the Add Connection dialog (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XN3f.png). Instead of "yedek\DUKKAN.db3" it should read something like "c:\Users\yedek\DUKKAN.db3". Use the "Browse..." button to find the db3 file.

Comment: thanks but
If I use the browse button
I get the error on different computers

http://i.imgur.com/SJdetwG.png

Comment: If you want to access the database from another computer you will have to share it, and configure in Add Connection as \\your-computer\shared-folder\DUKKAN.db3. Note that shared network access to sqlite is not the recommended solution: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork

Comment: im not use network.
this my computer database path , other pc different 
this my problem application startup in database file
ex: http://i.imgur.com/DSEsGxS.png